# Python3- How to call a function that accepts *args variably

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

#### The General Question

What is the python3.5+ syntax for calling a function that accepts *args, where *args references a variable with multiple items.

> I am self taught python; I can't help but think I am missing something rather elementary about how *args works. Feel free to point me to some necessary reading.

#### A Specific Question

When sorting a list of lists by columns using operator.itemgetter(*items), how can I provide *items variably?

#### Sample List

```
import operator

records = [
    ['0055613893 ', 'AP', 'BU', 'AA', '00005000012404R'],
    ['0048303110 ', 'MM', 'BU', 'AB', '00028230031385R'],
    ['0044285346 ', 'AP', 'BU', 'AA', '00062240050078R'],
    ['0048303108 ', 'MO', 'BU', 'AF', '00047780036604R'],
    ['0048751228 ', 'AP', 'ME', 'AC', '00000750013177R'],
    ['0045059521 ', 'AR', 'YT', 'AB', '00005430014570R']
]
```

If I wanted to sort this particular recordset by the 3rd column and then by the 1st column I would:

`records.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(3, 1))`

This, of course, works as one would expect.

What I'm getting at is how can I provide the "3, 1" to itemgetter() variably?

i.e.:

`indices = {insert some code here to provide itemgetter() what it needs}`
`records.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(indices))`

**I've Tried:**

tuple:

`indices = (3, 1)` 
or 
`indices = 3, 1`

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

list:

`indices = [3, 1]`

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

> It's never too late to be humbled by the basics. Thanks in advance for assisting in filling this gap in my python foundation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: As wwii pointed out, it might be time to reread the official Python 3 tutorial :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have

```
indices = [3, 1]
```

The you can use Python unpacking to give 3 and 1 to function calls:

```
itemgetter(*indices)
```

This is equivalent to

```
itemgetter(3, 1)
```

I'm not sure what versions of Python this works on.  This is one of the rapidly changing parts, so you might have to do a little reading if you're using an old version.